# Linq return only the list where the nested list doesn't match on filter

Tags: c#, linq

Hi have a List of Order objects which contains a List if OrderLineList objects.
Each of the OrderLineList object have a "sku" property.

What i want is to get all the OrderLineList which doesn't have the "sku" == "ABOLIVE".

Is there a way to do it ?

I tried something like that :

```
salefolder.OrderList.Where(o => o.OrderLineList.Except(o.OrderLineList.SelectMany(ol => ol.Sku.Select(s => s)).Any();
```

But it's not working well

Thanks

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far? Any code? We're not here to create code for you.

Comment: [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may help you.

Comment: I just edit my post and put my code, but it doesn't seems to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you OrderLineList items from each of your order items where the sku does not match "ABOLIVE".

```
void Main()
{
    List<Order> orders; /* some orders */

    IEnumerable<OrderLine> filteredOrderLines =
        orders
        .SelectMany(order => order.OrderLineList)
        .Where(orderLineList => orderLineList.sku != "ABOLIVE");
}

class Order
{
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLineList { get; set; }
}

class OrderLine
{
    public String sku { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer